# How to get prime numbers from string using permutations and combinations

Tags: python, combinations, primes, circular-permutations

Complete the following function to return a list of strings lesser than 999 which form prime numbers from a given string of numbers.
For example if the given string is **“23167”**. All the prime numbers less than or equal to 999 in the string are **2,3,23,31,7,167**. So, your function must return **[2,3,23,31,7,167]**. Although 23167 is a prime number we can ignore it because it is greater than 999.
**Output: should be list of integers**

```
def primenumber_from_string(string1):
    #your code goes here
    return []

if _name=='main_':
    #you can run any test cases here
    print(primenumber_from_string("8487934"))
```

Comment: what have you tried? stackoverflow is not a place to avoid having to do your lessons or homework. Show us what you have tried or how far you've got so that we can help with a more specific problem.

Comment: Suppose your string has k digits. Now consider a k-bit binary number, each bit mapping to a position in the k digit number. If the bit in that position is 1, use that digit, if 0, don't use that digit. Now notice that you only need to consider k-bit numbers with 3 or fewer bits set.

Comment: Shouldn't this function return `[2,23,3,31,167,67,7]` since 67 is also prime?

Answer (score 1):

Approach the problem systematically. Start with all the possible one-digit numbers, and check if they are prime. Then try all the possible two-digit numbers and see if they are prime. Then try all the possible three-digit numbers and check them all. Lastly show your accumulated results in the expected format.

Answer (score -1):

So it's a basic algorithmic problem. 
I'll give you some pseudo - code.
At this point, I'll only give you Brut-force solution, but I'll think about "proper" approach. 
So:
Take first digit -> check 
Second -> check
Third -> check
{ ... } 
compose two digit numbers -> check. 
When this is completed, put them into your list.  
For checking if number is prime fast ( O(sqrt(N)) ) you can use this function:

```
## Made by kam021m on: 12.12.2019  ##
## Resources used:
## * GeeksForGeeks article how to check primes fast
## *
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    i = 2
    while i*i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

This basically checks if number is prime by % (i) when i is lower than sqrt from n.

If I'll find faster solution, I will post it here.
EDIT 1: also wanted to ask, is it your homework or sth? Do you have time limits on it?